# Mavic 2 Enterprise do not show video after use it with DJI GO

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

Use case:

1) Connect with Mavic 2 Enterprise through DJI GO or DJI GO 4. Interesting thing that DJI GO recognizes drone as Mavic Pro and ask to use DJI GO 4. DJI GO 4 recognizes drone as Phantom4 and ask to use DJI GO.

2) Close DJI GO and reconnect to drone through mobile app with DJI SDK

As result there is no "onReceive" method call at VideoFeeder.
If you have used DJI PILOT app camera has been repaired and is work correctly until you will have not used DJI GO or DJI GO 4 again.
Is anybody know something about this strange Mavic 2E behavior?

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue? I have a similar issue with the Mavic 2 Pro on iOS. If I use my app that uses the SDK and then open DJI Go - DJI Go takes the feed. If I try to go back to my app I cannot get the video feed back without either power cycling the drone or disconnecting and reconnecting the remote's usb cable

Comment: @BrienCrean I post answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the DJI GO sets an invalid camera mode to some unsopported drones. There is several camera modes for DJI drones. They are desceibed [here](https://developer.dji.com/iframe/mobile-sdk-doc/android/reference/dji/common/camera/DJICameraSettingsDef.CameraMode.html) for the Android SDK. I think it should be the same for the IOS SDK. So I don't remember what mode was being set by the DJI GO app. It seems to be `Unkown` mode. Anyway in my app I use only `ShootPhoto` and `RecordVideo` modes, so if a camera mode on drone connecting was none of this two, I set 'ShootPhoto` by default.

Comment: I checked my camera mode and it was set to ShootPhoto even after going into DJI Go. I tried toggling the modes but it doesn't seem to work. However I did try changing the aspect ratio and that seems to have fixed it for me anyways. Thanks for sharing as it definitely helped me narrow down the issue